# Primefaces "Charts - Date" don't show series Label

Tags: primefaces

In my project like in Primefaces 6.1 showcase for "Charts - Date" don't show Labels, although in chartview model there is code: series1.setLabel("Series 1");

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/date.xhtml

How to get Labels for series on chart?

Answer (score 0):

finally I got to work - in showcase it is missing this line of code:

```
 dateModel.setLegendPosition("ne");
```